# Little question about Banach Space

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

It is possible that if I have a sequence $\{x_{nm}\}_{nm}$ in a Banach Space $V$ 
such that

1. $x_{nm}\to_{m\to\infty}y_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$
2. $y_n\to_{n\to \infty} x$

than $x_{nn}\to x$ ?

If it is not possible, what is a contro-example?

What conditions should I consider to get this result?

Comment: It's easy to construct a counter-example. Just pick distinct points $y,x \in V$. Let $x_{nm} = x$ if $n \neq m$ and let $x_{nn} = y$. Then $x_{nm} \to x$ and clearly $x \to x$ but $x_{nn} = y \not \to x$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, take the sequence $(x_{nm})_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^2}$ defined by
$$
x_{nm} = \frac{n}{m}, \qquad n,m\geq 1\,.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} x_{nm} = 0
$$
and of course $\lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$; but
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty} x_{nn} = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 =  1
$$